# how to run python 3 script on Unix with python 2 installation

Tags: python, version

I have a script which was written on Windows OS using Python 3.6.5.
I tried to run the code on Unix OS which has Python 2.6.6 installed, but received an error for the different Syntax and the unrecognized libraries.

Is there a way to use Python 3.X on my Unix server specifically for my code without upgrading the Python home version?

Comment: you don't need to upgrade py2 but merely install python3 alongside the builtin python. install the py3 libs with pip3 and you can start your app from the shell :>

Comment: You can either fix the syntax manually or install python3.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it directly. As I see it, your options are

- Install Python 3.x on the server and run the code using that
- Manually edit the code to support Python 2.x
- Use a tool such a [3to2](https://pypi.org/project/3to2/) to convert the code to suppport Python 2.x

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to run Python3.X using Python2.x.